# Same image for all rendered child components using react query, map and image api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, render, react-query

Issue: Getting same image for all TripList Items.

I have TripList data and I am mapping over it to create Component for each TripList item.

```
<h2>Travel Log</h2>
<div className={styles.tripList}>
  {data.map((el) => (
    <TripItem key={el.id} trip={el} />
  ))}
</div>
```

In TripItem, I am getting url using useQuery. URL is getting fetched according to city name is TripItem.

```
  const { data: url, isLoading } = useCityImage(trip?.place);
  if (isLoading) return <Spinner />;
  return (
    <div
      style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${url})` }}
      className={styles.tripListItem}
    >
      {trip.place}
    </div>
  );
```

Query function

```
const { data, isLoading } = useQuery({
queryFn: () => getLink(place),
queryKey: ['image'],
});
```

ImageApi

```
const res = await fetch(`${URL}&query=${place}&client_id=${KEY}`);
const data = await res.json();
return data.results[0].urls.small;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the query keys for each city's image are unique. In your current code, you are using the same query key ('image') for all cities. This might cause the useQuery hook to retrieve the same cached result for each city. Instead, you should include some unique identifier in the query key, such as the city name or ID.

```js
const { data, isLoading } = useQuery({
  queryFn: () => getLink(place),
  queryKey: ['image', place], // Include the city name in the query key
})
```